# Apache Camel read MongoDB Collection - not processing any rows

Tags: mongodb, apache-camel

I have the following Camel setup reading from MongoDB and writing to files, but it's not working:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    // create CamelContext
    SimpleRegistry sr = new SimpleRegistry();
    Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
    sr.put("mdb", mongo);
    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext(sr);

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        public void configure() {
            from("mongodb:mdb?database=demo&collection=person").to("file:data/outbox");
        }
    });

    // start the route and let it do its work
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(10000l);
}
```

There are 55 records returned from `db.person.find({})` in the MongoDB REPL shell.  However, when I run my app I get this in the logs and 0 records processed:

```
[                          main] DefaultExecutorServiceManager  DEBUG Created new ThreadPool for source: Consumer[mongodb://mdb?collection=person&database=demo] with name: mongodb://mdb?collection=person&database=demo. -> org.apache.camel.util.concurrent.RejectableThreadPoolExecutor@47d9a273[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0][mongodb://mdb?collection=person&database=demo]
[                          main] MongoDbTailingProcess          INFO  Starting MongoDB Tailable Cursor consumer, binding to collection: db: DB{name='demo'}, col: person
[                          main] MongoDbTailableCursorConsumer  DEBUG Stopping consumer: Consumer[mongodb://mdb?collection=person&database=demo]
[                          main] SharedProducerServicePool      DEBUG Stopping service pool: org.apache.camel.impl.SharedProducerServicePool@1bd4fdd
[                          main] GenericFileProducer            DEBUG Stopping producer: Producer[file://data/outbox]
[                          main] DefaultManagementAgent         DEBUG Unregistered MBean with ObjectName: org.apache.camel:context=camel-1,type=producers,name=GenericFileProducer(0x7205765b)
[                          main] MongoDbTailingProcess          INFO  Stopping MongoDB Tailable Cursor consumer, bound to collection: db: DB{name='demo'}, col: person
```

It looks like the cursor is opened, does nothing, then closes.  How can I get it to read my data?

Comment: I guess your main method is just ending after calling context.start, i.e. your JVM is dead. You should use camel main class to ensure your route keeps running, refer http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html

Comment: Yes as Gautam says its very likely that, see that link - and also check the javadoc of the start method.

Comment: I pasted some old code, see the `Thread.sleep(10000l);` that I added, it's the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

> > There is only one requisite to use tailable cursors: the collection must be a "capped collection"

From [The documentation here](https://camel.apache.org/mongodb.html)

I just have to create my collection in Mongo like so:

`db.createCollection('tc', {capped: true, size: 100})`

This allows it to read the data from the collection `tc`

Also, I cannot output directly to a file because Camel can't convert between Mongo object and File, so I have to do like this:

- For a `String`:

`from("mongodb:mdb?database=demo&collection=tc").convertBodyTo(String.class).to("file:data/outbox");`

- For a `Map`:

`from("mongodb:mdb?database=demo&collection=tc").convertBodyTo(Map.class).to("file:data/outbox");`